# Help with identifying a component on a PCB

Tags: pcb, identification

I'm trying to troubleshoot a malfunction smart-outlet. 
I think the marked component is a fuse. It's not conducting.
Is this a fuse?
Thanks[image]

Comment: The wiggly line in the component represents a fuse. The label underneath is FU1. The contact pads are quite large, and, I assume, the trace connects directly to line in. Umm, what question is there?

Comment: Yes, it is a fuse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely a fuse, the question is trying to find something that would replace it.  Would not recommend just shorting it...

Comment: I cannot tell what's the rate of the fuse. Nothing is written on it and there is no info on the Internet regarding this board.

Comment: I'm thinking of shorting it and use it because I'm not planning to use it with high power devices. My concern is that it might catch on fire. Is my concern valid?

Comment: I'm never one to tell other people to "throw caution to the winds."  I have an idea though, which is that instead of just shorting it, solder in a fuse holder for a fast-acting fuse.  Note that I am always paranoid that what the worse that could happen will happen, and the fuse won't blow fast enough to make a difference (FIRE).  However, those fast acting fuses blow for a reason, so maybe the risk you are taking is that the underlying problem (faulty component, bad design, etc.) is still there.